# Find in Struct multiple criteria

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

So I have a struct but I cannot figure out how to do a search with multiple criteria

```
BatchFile tmpBatch = BatchFileList.Find(x => x.BatchNumber.Equals(BatchNumber));
```

This is how I search for matches with a matching batch number.  But I need to search for items with a matching .BatchNumber and .Processor

I tried this but I don't believe this is the correct syntax

```
BatchFile tmpBatch = BatchFileList.Find(x => x.BatchNumber.Equals(BatchNumber) && x.Processor.Equals(Processor));
```

Comment: You don't believe? Have you tried running that code? Looks good to me.

Comment: What makes you believe it's wrong?

Comment: Other than preferring `==` to `Equals`, looks fine.

Comment: `Find` returns a single element.  Your question says `search for matches`, so if you're wanting all items that match your query, use `Where`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code you posted is using the correct syntax, and it will work just fine.

Comment: Thanks.  I am new to C# and I assumed my syntax was incorrect.  Apparently some trailing spaces were on the end of the string I was looking for.